# Backup script to FTP with timed subfolders

Tags: backup, bash, ftp, scripting

I want to make a backup script, that makes a `.tar.gz` of a folder I define, say fx `/root/tekkit/world`

This `.tar.gz` file should then be uploaded to a FTP server, named by the time it was uploaded, for example: `07-10-2012-13-00.tar.gz`

How should such backup script be written?

I already figured out the `.tar.gz` part - just need the naming and the uploading to FTP.

I know that FTP is not the most secure way to do it, but as it is non-sensitive data, and FTP is the only option I have, it will do.

### Edit:

I ended up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# have some path predefined for backup unless one is provided as first argument
BACKUP_DIR="/root/tekkit/world/"
TMP_DIR="/tmp/tekkitbackup/"
FINISH_DIR="/tmp/tekkitfinished/"
# construct name for our archive
TIME=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M)

if [ $1 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="$1"
fi

echo "Backing up dir ... $BACKUP_DIR"
mkdir $TMP_DIR
cp -R $BACKUP_DIR $TMP_DIR
cd $FINISH_DIR
tar czvfp tekkit-$TIME.tar.gz -C $TMP_DIR .

# create upload script for lftp
cat <<EOF> lftp.upload.script
open server
user user password
lcd $FINISH_DIR
mput tekkit-$TIME.tar.gz
exit
EOF

# start backup using lftp and script we created; if all went well print simple message and clean up 
lftp -f lftp.upload.script && ( echo Upload successfull ; rm lftp.upload.script )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you create cron job that is invoked at time you want to have backup created
after backup is created script will generate lftp script to upload file via FTP.

```
#!/bin/bash

# have some path predefined for backup unless one is provided as first argument
BACKUP_DIR="/tmp/test"
# construct name for our archive
TIME=$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M)

if [ $1 ]; then
    BACKUP_DIR="$1"
fi



echo "Backing up dir ... $BACKUP_DIR"
tar czvfp $TIME.tar.gz $BACKUP_DIR

# create upload script for lftp
cat <<EOF> lftp.upload.script
open ftp.server.tld
user username password
cd /target/directory
lcd /local/dir/where/tar/gz/archive/is
mput $TIME.tar.gz
exit
EOF

# start backup using lftp and script we created; if all went well print simple message and clean up 
lftp -f lftp.upload.script && ( echo Upload successfull ; rm lftp.upload.script )
```

Comment: Thanks - your script was what got me onto the right track.

Comment: I am curious...why does it have to "create upload script for lftp"?

Comment: because script is different every time since it has dynamic component "$TIME" which needs to be redefined every time and then supplied to FTP client to do slightly different set of commands than last time.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M`
tar cfz ${DATE}.tar.gz /root/tekkit/world
```

Or, with less typing:

```
tar cfz $(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M).tar.gz /root/tekkit/world
```

What happens?

```
$ DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M`
$ echo $DATE
07-10-2012-13-15
```

Comment: Good answer, but misses the FTP upload part.